# Providing data directly instead of file path

Tags: c++

I am dealing with a closed source library which needs some data to be passed to it in order to work. This data is around 150 MB. I have this data loaded in memory at the moment of initializing the main class of this lib which has the following constructor:

```
Foo::Foo(const std::string path_to_data_file);
```

`Foo` accepts the data as a file and there is no another overload that accepts the data directly (as string or byte array...).

The only possible way to call the library in my case is to write the data I have to disk then pass the path of the file to the library which is a very bad idea..

Is there is any technique to pass some kind of virtual path to the library that will result in reading the data from memory directly instead of the disk?

In other words, I am looking for (if it is exist or even possible) some technique that creates a virtual file that leads to memory address rather than physical address on the Disk.

I know that the right solution is to edit the library and isolate the data layer from the processing layer. However, this is not possible for now at least..

**Edit:**

the solution should be cross-platform. However, I can guess that those problem are usually OS dependent. So, I am looking for Linux and Windows solution.

The library is doing some Computer Vision stuffs and data is a kind of trained model

Comment: If you can't "fix" the library, then there's no other way.

Comment: What operating system? What is your library actually doing?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It should be cross-platform. However, I can guess that those problem are usually OS dependent. So, I am looking for Linux and Windows solution.
The library is doing some Computer Vision stuffs and data is a kind of trained model

Comment: That should go into your question!

Comment: Depending on how the library reads the file, you *might* be able to use a named pipe.  Pass the name of the pipe to the library, and when it opens that "file", you can then write your data into the pipe and the library can read it out.

Comment: You mean something like `std::stringstream` instead of `std::ifstream`, which would be be the argument to a `std::istream&` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably operating system specific. But you could put the data into some RAM or virtual memory based filesystem like [tmpfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs).

Then you don't need to change the library, you just pass it some file in a tmpfs file system.

BTW, on some OSes, if you have *recently* written a file, it sits in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (so is in RAM).

Notice also that reading 150Mb should not take much. If you can't put it on some tmpfs or RAM disk, try at least to use some SSD.

Comment: Even if putting the data on a RAM disk, it means writing to a file. And that three copies of the data might exist (the original in memory, the one on the disk, and the one the library reads).

Comment: It really depends a lot.